# Auto-assign IPv6 address via AWS and CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to have IPv6 addresses auto-assigned to EC2 instances within an autoscaling group+launch configuration?

VPC and subnets are all set up for IPv6. Manually created instances are ok.
I can also manually assign them, but I can't seem to find a way to do it in CloudFormation.

Answer (score 4):

The current status is that CloudFormation support for IPv6 is workable. Not fun or complete, but you can build a stack with it - I had to use 2 custom resources:

- The first is a generic resource that I use for other things and also reused here, to work around the missing feature to construct a subnet /64 CIDR block from a VPC's /56 auto-provided network
- The other I had to add specifically to work around a bug in the EC2 API that CloudFormation uses correctly.

Here is my setup:

### 1. Add IPv6 CIDR block to your VPC:

```
VPCipv6:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock"
  Properties:
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
    AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock: true
```

### 2. Extract the network prefix for creating /64 subnets:

[As explained in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917377/53538)

```
VPCipv6Prefix:
  Type: Custom::Variable
  Properties:
    ServiceToken: !GetAtt [ IdentityFunc, Arn ]
    Value: !Select [ 0, !Split [ "00::/", !Select [ 0, !GetAtt VPC.Ipv6CidrBlocks ] ] ]
```

`IdentityFunc` is an "identity function" implemented in Lambda for "custom variables", [as described in this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/625600/aws-cloudformation-custom-variables-in-templates/812040#812040). Unlike this linked answer, I implement the function directly in the same stack so it is easier to maintain. [See here for the gist](https://gist.github.com/guss77/2471e8789a644cac96992c4102936fb3).

### 3. Add an IPv6 default route to your internet gateway:

```
RouteInternet6:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
  Properties:
    RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTableMain
    DestinationIpv6CidrBlock: "::/0"
    GatewayId: !Ref IGWPublicNet
  DependsOn:
    - IGWNetAttachment
```

`IGWNetAttachment` is a reference to the `AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment` defined in the stack. If you don't wait for it, the route may fail to be set properly

### 4. Add an IPv6 CIDR block to your subnets:

```
SubnetA:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs { Ref: "AWS::Region" } ]
    CidrBlock: 172.20.0.0/24
    MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
    # The following does not work if MapPublicIpOnLaunch because of EC2 bug
    ## AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation: true 
    Ipv6CidrBlock: !Sub "${VPCipv6Prefix.Value}00::/64"
    VpcId:
      Ref: VPC
```

Regarding the `AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation` being commented out - this is normally what you want to do, but apparently, there's a bug in the EC2 API that prevents this from working - through no fault of CloudFormation. This is documented in [this AWS forums thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=840359), as well as the solution which I'll present here next.

### 5. Fix the `AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation` problem with another lambda:

This is the lambda setup:

```
IPv6WorkaroundRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
          - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Action:
        - sts:AssumeRole
    Path: "/"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: !Sub "ipv6-fix-logs-${AWS::StackName}"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - logs:CreateLogGroup
            - logs:CreateLogStream
            - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
      - PolicyName: !Sub "ipv6-fix-modify-${AWS::StackName}"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - ec2:ModifySubnetAttribute
            Resource: "*"

IPv6WorkaroundLambda:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: "index.lambda_handler"
    Code: #import cfnresponse below required to send respose back to CFN
      ZipFile:
        Fn::Sub: |
          import cfnresponse
          import boto3

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              if event['RequestType'] is 'Delete':
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS)
                return

              responseValue = event['ResourceProperties']['SubnetId']
              ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='${AWS::Region}')
              ec2.modify_subnet_attribute(AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation={
                                              'Value': True
                                            },
                                            SubnetId=responseValue)
              responseData = {}
              responseData['SubnetId'] = responseValue
              cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, "CustomResourcePhysicalID")
    Runtime: python2.7
    Role: !GetAtt IPv6WorkaroundRole.Arn
    Timeout: 30
```

And this is how you use it:

```
IPv6WorkaroundSubnetA:
  Type: Custom::SubnetModify
  Properties:
    ServiceToken: !GetAtt IPv6WorkaroundLambda.Arn
    SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
```

This call races with the autoscaling group to complete the setup, but it is very unlikely to lose - I ran this a few dozen times and it never had a problem to set the field correctly before the first instance boots.

Comment: Thanks for this @Guss. I still think this is an issue at the end of 2020.

Comment: Currently, in 2024, the `AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation` problem was fixed and you can just set that property on subnets and it will work - no need for lambda functions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and had a chat with AWS Support concerning this. The current state is that IPv6 support in CloudFormation is very limited.

We ended up creating Custom Resources for lots of IPv6-specific things. We have a Custom Resource that:

- Enables IPv6-allocation on a subnet
- Creates an Egress-Only Internet Gateway
- Adds a route to the Egress-Only Internet Gateway (the built-in Route resource says it "fails to stabilize" when pointing to an EIGW)

The Custom Resources are just Lambda functions that do the "raw" API call, and a IAM Role that grants the Lambda enough permissions to do that API call.