# How to determine ipv6 CIDR block prefix in AWS Cloudformation when creating subnets on a VPC

Tags: aws-cloudformation

AWS generates the ipv6 CIDR block for VPCs so its not possible to determine ahead of time. The generated CIDR block looks something like: `2a05:d018:84c:c500::/56` and is always size 56.

When creating a subnet you have to specify a size 64 block using the full prefixed value. E.g. `2a05:d018:84c:c501::/64`.

It's possible to look up the ipv6 CIDR blocks for a VPC in cloudformation, but this returns the full value, not just the prefix. To create a subnet we need to be able to append something `01::/64` to the prefix to create the 64 sized block for the subnet.

I've seen solutions that use a lambda function, but this greatly complicated the templates. I'd like to do this using just the built-in intrinsic functions available in the templates.

When deploying a VPC with ipv6 subnets in the same stack, how can you generate valid ipv6 CIDR blocks for the subnets?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a one liner that does the same thing using the [Fn::Cidr intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-cidr.html).

```
!Select [1, !Cidr [!Select [0, !GetAtt 'Vpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks'], 256, 64]]
```

For a given block `2a05:d018:84c:c500::/56` this will give you `2a05:d018:84c:c501::/64`

Increment the first index to get the next block.

```
!Select [2, !Cidr [!Select [0, !GetAtt 'Vpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks'], 256, 64]]
```

will give you `2a05:d018:84c:c502::/64`

Also here is a full minimal example including the crucial steps of using an `AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock` resource to attach the IPv6 block to the VPC and using the `DependsOn` property to make sure that the VPCCidrBlock is attached before the Subnet is created.

```
Resources:
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Sub '10.255.0.0/16'

  VpcCidrBlockIpv6:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
      AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock: true

  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    DependsOn: VpcCidrBlockIpv6 # Wait for IPv6 CIDR to be attached to VPC before creating subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
      AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation: true
      CidrBlock: !Sub '10.255.0.0/20'
      Ipv6CidrBlock: !Select [1, !Cidr [!Select [0, !GetAtt 'Vpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks'], 256, 64]]
```

Answer (score 4):

AWS VPC Service allows us to create a VPC and associate an Amazon provided /56 IPv6 CIDR block [We cannot provide our own CIDR]. 
Each subnet can have an IP block of /64. Which means that there can be theoretically 2^(64-56)subnets which is 2^8 = 256 subnets.

For calculating the Subnets for the IPv6 CIDR block, Cloudformation provides an intrinsic function !Cidr for us to do just that.

Syntax of the CIDR Block goes as follows:

```
!Cidr [ ipBlock, count, cidrBits ]
```

where

**count** --> The number of CIDRs to generate. Valid range is between 1 and 256.

**cidrBits** -->The number of subnet bits for the CIDR. For example, specifying a value "8" for this parameter will create a CIDR with a mask of "/24".

So our statement Becomes:

```
!Select [0, !Cidr [!Select [0, !GetAtt 'Vpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks'], 256, 64]]
```

So a sample template to create a VPC with 2 subnets with IPv6 attached to them looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    Resources:
        Vpc:
            Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
            Properties:
                CidrBlock: !Sub '10.255.0.0/16'

        VpcCidrBlockIpv6:
            Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock'
            Properties:
                VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
                AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock: true

        Subnet1:
            Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
            Properties:
                AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
                VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
                AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation: true
                CidrBlock: !Sub '${PrivateSubnetCIDR1}'
                Ipv6CidrBlock: !Select [0, !Cidr [!Select [0, !GetAtt 'Vpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks'], 256, 64]]

        Subnet2:
            Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
            Properties:
                VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
                AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation: true
                CidrBlock: !Sub '${PrivateSubnetCIDR2}'
                Ipv6CidrBlock: !Select [1, !Cidr [!Select [0, !GetAtt 'Vpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks'], 256, 64]]
```

Comment: For subnets you need: `DependsOn: VpcCidrBlockIpv6` resource attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to calculate the first subnet in YAML:

```
Fn::Sub:
    - "${VpcPart}${SubnetPart}"
    - SubnetPart: 01::/64
      VpcPart: !Select [0, !Split ['00::/56', !Select [0,!GetAtt YourVpc.Ipv6CidrBlocks]]]
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the prefix by using a combination of `Fn::Split` (on `00::/56`) and `Fn::Select` to get the prefix. Then you can append your own value to create the subnet CIDR blocks using `Fn::Join`. The following example assumes you have a VPC with one or more Ipv6 CIDR blocks associated with it.

Use this value for the `Ipv6CidrBlock` property on the subnet.

```
{
    "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
            {
                "Fn::Select": [
                    0,
                    {
                        "Fn::Split": [
                            "00::/56",
                            {
                                "Fn::Select": [
                                    0,
                                    {
                                        "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                            "Vpc",
                                            "Ipv6CidrBlocks"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "01::/64"
        ]
    ]
}
```